# How to find the maximum multiplication of two columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, multiplication

I have a table which contains two columns.

I want to find the maximum multiplication of these two columns and how many of them have this maxmimum value?

I have tried the max of the multiplication of two columns

But it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you share what you have done.

Comment: What do you mean with `max of the multiplication of two columns`? Is it the value contained inside the column? In this case, please provide an example to clarify your issue, otherwise it is very hard to understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max()`:

```
select max(col1 * col2)
from t;
```

To find the number that match:

```
select count(*)
from t
where (t.col1 * t.col2) = (select max(t2.col1 * t2.col2) from t t2);
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*, 
             rank() over (order by col1 * col2 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL and it gives me an error about select count(*). Is there a way to solve thsi?

Comment: @Ellie . . . MySQL supports `count(*)`.